# How to get the iPhone's screen width in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

I want to resize an Image frame to be a square that takes the same width of the iPhone's screen and consequently the same value (screen width) for height.

The following code don't work cause it gives the image the same height of the view.

```swift
var body: some View {
    Image("someImage")
        .resizable()
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
        .clipped()
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you have a different issue, because you are working with `Image`. (And yes, there are two fairly simple ways to get the screen width, but I don't think they will solve your problem.) Have you tried adding this modifier? `.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)`

Comment: Second comment... I upvoted the answer by @DoesData because it's one to two `SwiftUI` ways of doing this (and didn't downvote the answer from @MehmetAliVataniar even though it makes some serious non-SwiftUI assumptions. The second way - found in the following question, uses subclassing `UIHostingController` and may get you *much* more things you can do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57441654/swiftui-repaint-view-components-on-device-rotation/57442517#comment101361813_57442517

Comment: maybe this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57577462/get-width-of-a-view-using-in-swiftui/57577752#57577752

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get width of a view using in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57577462/get-width-of-a-view-using-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 123):

You can create a `UIScreen` extension for the same. Like:

```
extension UIScreen{
   static let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
   static let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
   static let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
}
```

**Usage**:

```
UIScreen.screenWidth
```

Comment: GeometryReader is the way to go! It will update according to system event such as orientation change

Comment: And this would require UIKit, so no more building that SwiftUI for Mac.

Comment: thanks for this. hopefully soon there will be a swiftui native code for it. but this worked for what I needed as my was already nested within another view so Geometry Reader wasn't working for me. I couldn't get global width and height.

Comment: The `.size` isn't necessary on `UIScreen.main.bounds`, so you can use `UIScreen.main.bounds.width/height` directly, eliminimating one step and making the raw calls without the exception more viable.

Comment: @Jeehut: deprecated since iOS 2.0

Comment: seems cleaner than using the geometryReader

Comment: [`UIScreen.main.bounds`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/1617838-bounds) actually does update with orientation changes ("the value of this property may change when the device rotates"). `nativeBounds` is the one that does not.

Comment: This is wrong (and has been wrong for many years). There's no guarantee your app is running on the main window.

Answer (score 67):

Try using [Geometry Reader](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryreader)

```
let placeholder = UIImage(systemName: "photo")! // SF Symbols

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Image(uiImage: placeholder) 
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.width, alignment: .center)
            // .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            .clipped()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I tested the code but, at least in my preview, the image was still the same size of the screen instead of a square.

Comment: [@RubensNeto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6316195/rubens-neto) - I'm not sure about a preview since I am not running OSX Catalina, but running this code on simulator / device yields the above output where the width / height are equal. I hope that helps.

Comment: The problem with GeometryReader is that it applies only to the level you are at. If you trying to write a generic modal pop-up and want to obscure the screen below the pop-up, GeometryReader will not give you any information to do that. To do that properly requires a lot of code.

Comment: @P.Ent have you looked at [GeometryProxy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryproxy)? "A proxy for access to the size and coordinate space (for anchor resolution) of the container view."

Comment: Note that there is a typo in this answer....the height should be geometry.size.height (not width)

Answer (score 28):

I've come up with a solution using Environment Keys, by creating the following:

```swift
private struct MainWindowSizeKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: CGSize = .zero
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var mainWindowSize: CGSize {
        get { self[MainWindowSizeKey.self] }
        set { self[MainWindowSizeKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

Then by reading the size from where the window is created:

```swift
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.mainWindowSize, proxy.size)
        }
    }
}
```

Finally I can directly get the window size in any SwiftUI view, and it changes dynamically (on device rotation or window resizing on macOS):

```swift
@Environment(\.mainWindowSize) var mainWindowSize
```

Comment: Highly recommended if you are planning to support MacOS and split view on iPads. Once you define the UIScreen.main.bounds value you have to always force an update. But this example since an environment variable allows you to use it in multiple levels in your app.

Comment: Great tip! I use this to determine the height of a chart, a % of the visible space, which is included within a ScrollView so that the chart is the predominant thing on the screen real estate, but you can still get a sense that there is more below.

Comment: I'm not sure how this works. I've tried it and putting `@Environment(\.mainWindowSize) var mainWindowSize` into my views and trying to call `Text("\(mainWindowSize.width)")` for example just always shows 0.00000. I'm missing somerthing? iOS 16.4 / Xcode 14.3

Comment: @Rillieux Have you wrapped the proper root `View` with `GeometryReader`? Also SwiftUI sometimes does not pass Environment variables when you're within a `.sheet()` modifier for example so this might be why you're getting the default 0 value (in this case you have to pass it again to the contained `View` with `.environment(\.mainWindowSize, main)`, having `@Environment(\.mainWindowSize) var mainWindowSize` defined in the parent `View`).

Comment: Not work in Xcode preview but work for simulators and devices.

Answer (score 27):

You can use UIScreen.main.bounds **.width** or **.height**

```
.frame(
   width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width,
   height:UIScreen.main.bounds.height
)
```

Comment: GeometryReader is the way to go! It will update according to system event such as orientation change

Comment: @Sajjon GeometryReader also breaks your screen and causes things to expand unnecessarily causeing more headaches.

Comment: This is the certain way to know the HARDWARE screen size, as specified in the question. And more importantly, if you need to get the hardware screen _height_ then GeometryReader will fail you -- it subtracts out the status bar at the top of the screen!  And, thankfully, `let hardwareScreenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size` works just fine in SwiftUI.

Comment: @Justacoder you can wrap GeometryReader in .background() or hide it in ZStack to avoid layout problems

Comment: [`UIScreen.main.bounds`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/1617838-bounds) actually does update with orientation changes ("the value of this property may change when the device rotates"). `nativeBounds` is the one that does not.

Answer (score 12):

The simplest way would be to make the image resizable and set the aspect ratio to 1.0:

```
var body: some View {
    Image("someImage")
       .resizable()
       .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)
}
```

Comment: This is the officially documented answer. I don't get why other answers got so many upvotes and not this one.

Comment: @Farid Perhaps because the question is "How to get the iPhone's screen width in SwiftUI?", but the intentions was "resize an Image frame to be a square that takes the same width of the iPhone's screen"

This answer is perfect in relation to the Image, while others answer the direct question about the screen size. Both are valuable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I fix it by apply GeometryReader to get the screen width and use it.

```
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack(spacing: 20) {
                    ForEach(Array(zip(tabBarOptions.indices, tabBarOptions)),
                            id: \.0,
                            content: {
                        index, name in
                        TabBarItem(currentTab: $currentTab,
                                   namespace: namespace,
                                   tabBarItemName: name,
                                   tab: index)
                    })
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .frame(width: proxy.size.width)
//                .border(.red, width: 4)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .frame(height: 80)
//            .border(.green, width: 2)
            .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
```