# How is GeometryReader wrapping ContentView affecting environmentObject assigned to that view?

Tags: swiftui, geometryreader

I have added `.environmentObject(AuthViewModel())` to ContentView which is also wrapped inside geometryReader inside struct conforming to App called MyApp.
Exactly like it's reccomended in this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71970454/14743849 .

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                       ContentView()
                           .environmentObject(AuthViewModel())
                           .environment(\.mainWindowSize, proxy.size)
                   }
        }
```

I started using my environment object  and I have noticed that it is affecting my AuthViewModel properties by reseting their values. I think it's also worth to mention that app is not allowed to be used in landscape.

After removing geometryReader everything works fine.

Comment: The only safe way to initialize an observable object is with a StateObject. Don’t initialize in the body.

Comment: So if I initialize it with StateObject and then pass that to environmentObject problem i have experienced will be fixed? @loremipsum

Comment: Yes it will be fixed

Comment: Each time there are changes that affect the app (say, interface orientation changes), the view hierarchy is re-rendered by calling the "body". Each time body is called, your code creates another instance of the `AuthViewModel`, effectively, resetting the data. That would be my guess why it happens. @loremipsum's suggestion is a great solution.