# SwiftUI disable auto rotation of views

Tags: swiftui, screen-orientation, device-orientation

I have a SwiftUI app which should support landscape and portrait. However I want the behaviour of the Camera.app in iOS. When the device is rotated only the buttons are rotated when switching landscape/portrait all other content is as is.

So I want to disable the auto rotation of some views and enable rotation for some views. Not sure how to implement it.

```
struct ContentView: View {
   var view: some View {
       HStack {
           Text("Hello") // Don't rotate
           Text("World") // Rotate
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, I tried [HERE_1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57442517/3146021) or [HERE_2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57475556/3146021) to detect rotation and rotate the "Hello" text while rotate device.

I had already tried using link_2 and change a bit of code as below:

In **SceneDelegate**:

```
func windowScene(_ windowScene: UIWindowScene, didUpdate previousCoordinateSpace: UICoordinateSpace, interfaceOrientation previousInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, traitCollection previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection) {
        switch windowScene.interfaceOrientation {
        case .landscapeLeft:
            model.angel = 90
        case .landscapeRight:
            model.angel = -90
        case .portraitUpsideDown:
            model.angel = 180
        default:
            model.angel = 0
        }
    }
```

In **Model**:

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    let objectWillChange = ObservableObjectPublisher()

    var angel: Double = 0 { willSet { objectWillChange.send() } }
}
```

And in **ContentView**:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Hello")
                .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: model.angel))
            Text("World")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that also rotates `Text("World")`... I'm looking for a way to disable the auto rotation.

Comment: @PeterWarbo huh? as your comment code, I see your expected is rotate `Text("World")`. My idea is detect rotation and rotate which item expect **Don't Rotate**

Comment: Unfortunately, the new SwiftUI template does not have a delegate.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to replicate the behavior of the default iOS Camera App. This uses the `@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor` wrapper available in iOS 14+ to add a custom App Delegate to the SwiftUI App lifecycle that reports a subset of the `UIInterfaceOrientationMask`s.

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, ObservableObject {
    @Published var shouldRotate: Bool = false

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        let orientationMask: [UIInterfaceOrientationMask] = shouldRotate ? [.all] : [.portrait]
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask(orientationMask)
    }
}
```

(I have also included a published property, `shouldRotate`, to allow re-enabling all orientations such as if showing the photo browser.)

Note the final possible orientations will be the overlap between those listed in your app's info.plist and the `.all` or `.portrait`.

**MyApp.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor private var appDelegate: AppDelegate

    @State private var degToFaceUp: Double = 0

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(degToFaceUp: degToFaceUp)
            .onAppear() //Need to have onAppear first before we are able to attach the listener
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)) { _ in
                var offset: Int = 0
                switch UIDevice.current.orientation {
                case .portrait:
                    offset = 0
                case .portraitUpsideDown:
                    offset = 2
                case .landscapeLeft:
                    offset = 1
                case .landscapeRight:
                    offset = -1
                case .unknown:
                    offset = 0
                case .faceUp:
                    offset = 0
                case .faceDown:
                    offset = 0
                @unknown default:
                    print("** New UIDeviceOrientation, add case to the degToFaceTop")
                    offset = 0
                }
                degToFaceUp = Double(offset) * 90.0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Our custom App Delegate is specified, as well as a passed-in binding that calculates the number of degrees to rotate the small views to face upwards.

**ContentView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appDelegate: AppDelegate //Optional, just showing that SwiftUI automatically injects the appDelegate into the environment when it conforms to ObservableObject.
    
    var degToFaceUp: Double //Will be passed in

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Hello")
            Text("World")
                .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: degToFaceUp))
        }
    }
}
```

**Final Result**

[image: iPhone Screenshot showing landscape orientation but with elements still in portrait interface orientation]

See that the bar to swipe to the Home Screen is still on the right, just like the default iOS Camera App. You will need to test this with a physical device or simulator, not the SwiftUI Preview.

Tested Xcode 15.1, iOS 16.4