# SwiftUI how to Reorder in Landscape and Portrait

Tags: swiftui

we use a custom gridView to display all Products in a grid.
the problem is... we need to reorder if the Device is in Landscape or Portait.

How can we do that?

```
ModularGridStyle(columns: 2, rows: 3)
```

columns and rows needs to be different if device is in landscape.

here is the View

```
var body: some View {
Grid(self.products) { product in
                    Text("\(product.name)")

                }
                .gridStyle(
                    ModularGridStyle(columns: 2, rows: 3)
                )
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI Repaint View Components on Device Rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57441654/swiftui-repaint-view-components-on-device-rotation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `verticalSizeClass`.

```swift
@Environment(\.verticalSizeClass) private var verticalSizeClass: UserInterfaceSizeClass?

var body: some View {
    Grid(self.products) { Text(verbatim: "\($0.name)") }
        .gridStyle(
            ModularGridStyle(
                columns: self.verticalSizeClass == .compact ? 3 : 2, 
                rows: self.verticalSizeClass == .compact ? 2 : 3
            )
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer using a GeometryReader to setup different views for portrait/landscape. Of course, it's a bit redundant, but usually you have other properties that change as well:

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader() { g in
        if g.size.width < g.size.height {
            // view in portrait mode
            Grid(self.products) { product in
                Text("\(product.name)")
            }
            .gridStyle(
                ModularGridStyle(columns: 2, rows: 3)
            )
        } else {
            // view in landscape mode
            Grid(self.products) { product in
                Text("\(product.name)")
            }
            .gridStyle(
                ModularGridStyle(columns: 3, rows: 2)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is possible approach:

```swift
private var deviceOrientationPublisher = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for:
    UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)

@State var dimention: (Int, Int) = (2, 3)
var body: some View {
    Grid(self.products) { product in
        Text("\(product.name)")

    }
    .gridStyle(
        ModularGridStyle(columns: dimention.0, rows: dimention.1)
    )
    .onReceive(deviceOrientationPublisher) { _ in
        self.dimention = UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape ? (3, 2) : (2, 3)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked for a more simple & elegant solution -

and found this code in - [hackingwithswift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-detect-device-rotation)

```
// Our custom view modifier to track rotation and
// call our action
struct DeviceRotationViewModifier: ViewModifier {
let action: (UIDeviceOrientation) -> Void

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
      content
        .onAppear()
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)) { _ in
            action(UIDevice.current.orientation)
        }
    }
}



// A View wrapper to make the modifier easier to use
extension View {
    func onRotate(perform action: @escaping (UIDeviceOrientation) -> Void) -> some View {
        self.modifier(DeviceRotationViewModifier(action: action))
    }
}


// An example view to demonstrate the solution
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var orientation = UIDeviceOrientation.unknown

var body: some View {
    Group {
        if orientation.isPortrait {
            Text("Portrait")
        } else if orientation.isLandscape {
            Text("Landscape")
        } else if orientation.isFlat {
            Text("Flat")
        } else {
            Text("Unknown")
        }
    }
    .onRotate { newOrientation in
        orientation = newOrientation
    }
}
}
```