# SwiftUI: How to let ScrollView move one item once

Tags: uiscrollview, swiftui

My image list is a horizontal scroll list. And image in the list is presented as full screen width. By default, it is moving continuously, however, I want to let it move one item at a time, how could I do that.

I search it here, there is some similar questions related with Android but not iOS, specifically SwiftUI.

```
private struct PresentedImageList: View {
    var images: [ImageViewModel]

    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { gr in
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 6) {
                    ForEach(self.images, id: \.self) { image in
                        KFImage(source: .network(image.fileURL))
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: gr.size.width)
                            .aspectRatio(1.77, contentMode: .fit)

                    }
                }
            }.background(Color.black)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `SwiftUI` this is not available. so need to do using `UIKit`

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var images: [ImageViewModel]

  var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { gr in
        ScrollViewUI(hideScrollIndicators: false) {
            HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(self.images, id: \.self) { image in
                    VStack {
                        KFImage(source: .network(image.fileURL))
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: gr.size.width-6,alignment: .center)
                            .aspectRatio(1.77, contentMode: .fit)
                    }
                    .frame(width: gr.size.width,alignment: .center)
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**`ScrollViewUI`**

```
struct ScrollViewUI<Content: View>: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

  var content: () -> Content
  var hideScrollIndicators: Bool = false

  init(hideScrollIndicators: Bool, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
      self.content = content
      self.hideScrollIndicators = hideScrollIndicators
  }

  func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ScrollViewController<Content> {
      let vc = ScrollViewController(rootView: self.content())
      vc.hideScrollIndicators = hideScrollIndicators
      return vc
  }

  func updateUIViewController(_ viewController: ScrollViewController<Content>, context: Context) {
      viewController.hostingController.rootView = self.content()
  }
}
```

**`ScrollViewController`**

```
class ScrollViewController<Content: View>: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

  var hideScrollIndicators: Bool = false

  lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
      let view = UIScrollView()
      view.delegate = self
      view.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = !hideScrollIndicators
      view.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = !hideScrollIndicators
      view.bounces = false
      view.backgroundColor = .clear
      view.isPagingEnabled = true
      return view
  }()

  init(rootView: Content) {
      self.hostingController = UIHostingController<Content>(rootView: rootView)
      self.hostingController.view.backgroundColor = .clear
      super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
  }

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  var hostingController: UIHostingController<Content>! = nil

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      view.addSubview(scrollView)
      view.backgroundColor = .clear

      self.makefullScreen(of: self.scrollView, to: self.view)
      self.hostingController.willMove(toParent: self)
      self.scrollView.addSubview(self.hostingController.view)
      self.makefullScreen(of: self.hostingController.view, to: self.scrollView)
      self.hostingController.didMove(toParent: self)
  }

  func makefullScreen(of viewA: UIView, to viewB: UIView) {
      viewA.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      viewB.addConstraints([
          viewA.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewB.leadingAnchor),
          viewA.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewB.trailingAnchor),
          viewA.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewB.topAnchor),
          viewA.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewB.bottomAnchor),
      ])
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, we still need to wrap it into UIKit. Hope Apple will update some modifier for convenient use. Thanks, it is working now, the ```ScrollView``` could scroll as page mode. Just one inconsistent, after implement this code, the ```ScrollView``` is pinned to the top of the view instead of the middle. Maybe some constraint need to be changed, I'm looking into it.

Comment: Add one more line of constraint ```viewA.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewB.centerYAnchor)``` would fix the issue.

Comment: Oh, one more thing, when I rotate my iPhone, the ScrollView didn't behave good, it showed just half of image when scrolling and struct there after.

Comment: @ChuckZHB for that i think need to reload UI again.

Comment: Do I need to reload UI in UIScrollView or in contentView of SwiftUI. Could you show me more details about it like how to trigger it. I'm not familiar with wrapping UIKit in SwiftUI.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57441654/swiftui-repaint-view-components-on-device-rotation You can get idea from this link.

Comment: Cool, I would like to go through it.

Answer (score 3):

If you have one ScrollView appearing, then you could just simply add

```
 .onAppear {
                UIScrollView.appearance().isPagingEnabled = true
            }
```

this code at the end of the ScrollView Closure.

***entire code would be***

```
private struct PresentedImageList: View {
    var images: [ImageViewModel]

    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { gr in
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 6) {
                    ForEach(self.images, id: \.self) { image in
                        KFImage(source: .network(image.fileURL))
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: gr.size.width)
                            .aspectRatio(1.77, contentMode: .fit)

                    }
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                UIScrollView.appearance().isPagingEnabled = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However if you have multiple ScrollView appearing, that added code will affect all of the ScrollViews appearing.

So in that case you could use TabView, instead of HStackView.

```
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { gr in
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                TabView(alignment: .top, spacing: 6) {
                    ForEach(self.images, id: \.self) { image in
                        KFImage(source: .network(image.fileURL))
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: gr.size.width)
                            .aspectRatio(1.77, contentMode: .fit)

                    }
                }
                
             //.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle.page(indexDisplayMode: .never)) 
             // --> in case you don't want the indicators
            }
        }
    }
```