# In Swiftui How to automatically close modal with rotation to landscape

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I currently use an landscape environmentobject based on this code - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58503841/412154

Within my view I have modals that appear and disappear appropriately using @State/@Binding depending on a "Done" Button press.  My app does show a different view when rotated to landscape and I would like for the modal to dismiss automatically on the rotation, but couldn't figure out how to change the @binding var based on another @ennvironmentobject

Here is a simplified sample of my Modal View

```
struct StepsView: View {
    @Binding var isPresented:Bool
    @EnvironmentObject var orientation:Orientation

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
              Text("Step")
              }
             .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                    //print("Dismissing steps view...")
                    self.isPresented = false
                }) {
                    Text("Done").bold()
                })
            }
```

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appreciate @davidev's answer but I wanted each Modal to act a little differently so I did it this way

```
struct StepsView: View {
    @Binding var isPresented:Bool
    @EnvironmentObject var orientation:Orientation
    
    private var PortraitView:some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
              Text("Modal")
              }
             .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                    self.isPresented = false
                }) {
                    Text("Done").bold()
                })
            }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        buildView(isLandscape: orientation.isLandScape, isShowing: &isPresented)
    }

    func buildView(isLandscape:Bool, isShowing:inout Bool) -> AnyView {

        if !isLandscape {
            return AnyView(PortraitView)
        } else {
            isShowing = false
            return AnyView(EmptyView())
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible approach with extending the Device class with a variable which keeps track of the opened modal View.

```
import Combine

final class Orientation: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isLandscape: Bool = false {
        willSet {
            objectWillChange.send()
            
            if (newValue)
            {
                self.showModal = false
            }
        }
    }
    
    @Published var showModal : Bool = false
}
```

Whenever landscape changes, and the orientation is landscape, showModal will be set to false.

Here the ContentView..

```
struct ContentView6: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var orientation:Orientation
    // 1.
    @State private var showModal = false
    
    var body: some View {
      
       Button("Show Modal") {
          // 2.
        self.orientation.isLandscape.toggle()
       // 3.
       }.sheet(isPresented: self.$orientation.isLandscape) {
        ModalView(isPresented: self.$orientation.isLandscape).environmentObject(self.orientation)
        }
    }
}
```